# How to use powershell to search remote servers for folders

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to search multiple remote servers with multiple logical disks for certain folders and want to get the folder path as output. My script is below, its working but it keeps on giving me results from one logical disk only.

for example my server has 5 logical disks but my script keeps on searching C:\ for the folder Tools, and never moves forward to searching other logical disks

```
$Servers= @( "Server01" )
foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    gwmi -ComputerName $Server Win32_LogicalDisk | 
        where {$.DriveType -eq '3'} | 
        select-object DeviceID | 
        ForEach {
            Get-ChildItem ($.DeviceID + "\") -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        } | Where-Object { ($.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and ( $.Name -eq "Tools")} | 
        Select name, FullName 
}
```

Comment: @Paul did you edit the code in the question? According to the edit it looks like it.

Comment: @matt no i only did formatting, the code was already fixed

Comment: @Paul Sorry about that. History makes it seem like you did...

Comment: @matt no prob, i was a bit puzzled as well after reading mjolinors answer because the code was ok in that regard

Answer (score 0):

All of those $. references in your pipeline should be $_.